# copy projects between different computers

Tags: brightway

assuming I have the same version of bw2 on two different machines. Can I just copy paste the contents of the folder `projects.dir` to transfer all the data of that project from a machine to the other without risks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier and safer to use the utility functions `backup_project_directory` and `restore_project_directory`, though these functions are functionally the same as copy-pasting the directory (they just compress and archive to a single file). This should be completely compatible between computers running the same OS; switching architectures or to something really exotic could require exporting the SQLite3 databases to a CSV, but this, so far, a theoretical problem.